# Loading file content in matlab and save it to a variable

Tags: matlab, file, variables, types

I need to save a file content into a variable with matlab. The file I'm talking about is a picture. I have the function base64_encode in matlab which allow me to convert the value of the file contents to the base64.
For now, I can get the file content by typing :

```
type('test.tif')
```

It does return something very long with special character. But, when I try tp save it on some var like :

```
var = type('test.tif')
```

It returns me the error :

```
Error using type
Too many output arguments.
```

Do you have a idea how can I archive this ?

Comment: [`type`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/type.html) is not for loading data. For reading images, try reading MATLAB's [Importing Images](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/importing-images.html) documentation.

Comment: Ok, it helps me. But I really need to find a way to convert the string of the picture with base64_encode. Is their a way to archive this ?

Comment: If you're talking about [this `base64_encode`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32207-matlab-3d-figure-to-3d--x-html/content/functions/base64_encode.m), you simply need to pass the filename to the function, and it will return the base64 encoding of the image.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for ! Thanks :)